# how to implement alphabetic scrollbar like in music player app ios /

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, scrollbar, uislider

I need to implement *alphabetic scrollbar* like in music app . Can anyone help me with that code . As i searched on internet and was not able to get that code anywhere.

I need that scrollbar on *uitableview* in right side

i need scrollbar like this one.

[image: scrollbar]

Comment: can u show some example how to need

Comment: yes, i have updated that also . @ anbu

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface yourViewcontroller ()
{
 NSArray * IndexTitles;
}

  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

  IndexTitles = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z"];

 }

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return IndexTitles;
}

 // - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
              sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title 
              atIndex:(NSInteger)index
// {
   //  return index;
// }
```

need reference follow this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/)

Comment: Yes i got that scrollbar, but i need functionality to scroll to index when i click on it . eg :- when i click on S in the scrollbar , it scrolls the table down to people starting from the letter S. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: The link which u shared above has static data in it . But i am fetching abadressbook in uitable view . So how can i implement this done . @ Anbu.Karthik

Comment: both are same bro, when u get the name in ABAddressbook after that use NSSortDesiptor for sort then load the data in to table , simple

Comment: simple my friend, above coding are fine no need to change , u need to follow this steps, step 1: when u get the first name, last name from address book store into array. step 2 : in here sort your array using NSSortdecriptor step 3 : when it is over [yourtableview reloadData]. thats all

Comment: you need to add ```sectionForSectionIndexTitle``` method to return an Integer ( this is section number ) you want to go to when a character is clicked. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

I used it following way to display alphabet scroll bar and also go to that section when clicked on any alphabet. 
Note: My table view has n sections with each section having only 1 row ( thats my requirement). So clicking on any of the character will scroll to that section.
This also takes care of case where you click on an alphabet which does not have matching results.

For example, you click on `F`. There is no entry in indexSectionTitles starting with `F`, its there only till D ( Doll ). So i will try to move to a section before `F` i.e. `E`. So this goes on and use will be taken to section with nearest character before it.

```
var indexTitles = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
var indexSectionTitles: [String] = ["Apple", "Ball", "Car", "Doll"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
    if indexSectionTitles.indexOf(title) != nil {
        return indexSectionTitles.indexOf(title)!
    }
    else {
        let char = title as NSString
        let prevCharIndex = getPrevName(char)
        print("prevCharIndex; ", prevCharIndex)
        return prevCharIndex
    }
}

func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return indexTitles
}

func getPrevName(title: NSString) -> Int {
    if title.isEqualToString("") {
        return 0
    }
    let charInt = title.characterAtIndex(0) - 1
    let charStr = String(UnicodeScalar(charInt))
    if indexSectionTitles.indexOf(charStr) != nil {
        return indexSectionTitles.indexOf(charStr)!
    }
    return getPrevName(charStr)
}
```